# Pass array as individual params to a php function

Tags: php, parameters, arguments, call

**Solution**

Thanks to [noufalcep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26353767/2803348), I got it working by using

```
public function __call($method, $params){
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->_rpc, $method), $params);
}
```

**Original Question**

I've made a class which wraps another class, [jsonrpc](http://jsonrpcphp.org/), for ease of use in my project.

jsonrpc uses `public function __call($method, $params)` to cope with any sort of generic method.

I'm also using the same in my class, but this means I have to convert the `$params` array into individual variables to be passed in as arguments to jsonrpc's `__call()`.

How do I change the array of `$params` to multiple arguments?

In my wrapper class, I've tried using `...` to provide the arguments, but it only seems to work when instantiating the array with `[]`.

An easy solution would be to edit how the jsonrpc class deals with it's params, but I'd prefer to leave its source untouched.

What I've tried (obviously each `__call` was tried separately, and not concurrently...)

```
class Wrap{
    //Could have been great, but doesn't work.
    public function __call($method, $params){
        $params = array_values($params);
        return $this->_rpc->$method(...$params);
    }

    //Horrible, but works
    public function __call($method, $params){
        switch (count($params)) {
            case 0:
                return $this->_rpc->$method();
                break;
            case 1:
                return $this->_rpc->$method($params[0]);
                break;
            case 2:
                return $this->_rpc->$method($params[0], $params[1]);
                break;
            case 3:
                return $this->_rpc->$method($params[0], $params[1], $params[2]);
                break;
            case 4:
                return $this->_rpc->$method($params[0], $params[1], $params[2], $params[3]);
                break;
            default:
                die("Horrible way doesn't have enough cases!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting when you use `...` ?

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia It was a syntax error: Unexpected '.', expecting ')'. Nouflacep had the right idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26353767/2803348)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
public function __call($method, $params){
    return call_user_func_array($this->_rpc->$method(),$params)
}
```

Comment: I had to use `call_user_func_array(array($this->_rpc, $method), $params);` but it worked.